# How do you format python code in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, formatting, visual-studio-code, autopep8

Opened a ticket with AutoPep8, but when I installed the autopep8 extension, it doesn't seem to find the module. When I change the config to tell it where it is a format doesn't do anything. Formating in terminal does however. Any ideas? https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8/issues/349#issuecomment-335662565

Comment: Can you show a picture of what is happening? What are you wanting from the formatting?

Comment: Have you tried the [default Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.python) yet?

Comment: Got a 404 on that link

Comment: Updated link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python

Comment: I installed that and I get the same result. Also it warns that its not a recommended interpretor.

Comment: Could it be that you are using a different python installation on the command line vs in VS Code?

Comment: I’m using the “python” extension as linked above. I also have python normal installation on my computer.

Comment: related: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/formatting and https://stackoverflow.com/q/77283648/11107541

Answer (score 13):

Install the below python packages for Python Code Format supporting in Windows

```
pip install autopep8

pip install pylint
```

Once you have successfully installed the packages, Open the code in vs code -> Press Ctrl + A and Ctrl + K, it will format the code.

Comment: This did not work for me. However, after running this command, I also went to the extensions of VSCode and installed the "autopep8" extensions. I then updated my user settings json file with "[python]": { "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.autopep8"} and now VSCode is formatting my python code. This is on a mac, if that matters to you

Answer (score 6):

autopep8 is listed as a requirement. On mac, using brew, you can install it as follows:

```
brew install autopep8
```

Comment: The other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60880116/1705829) recommends `pylint`, is it needed for Mac to autoformat code?

Comment: This did not work for me. However, after running this command as well as the commands of `pip install autopep8` and `pip install pylint` I installed a VSCode extensions called "autopep8". I wrote more specific instructions for making it work in a comment to an answer by @Dhandapani Sudhakar on this page you're currently on

Answer (score 3):

you should try black.

```bash
pip install black
```

and then open the auto format option in vscode when save and modify the python format provider to black in vscode settings. enjoy the black.