# Visual Studio Code - missing "Select Linter"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I just installed the latest version (1.83.1) of VSC on Ubuntu.  I plan to develop in Python, and am just getting started using Linters.

I have installed the VSC extensions for Python, including the Pylance extension.  I also installed the pylint and flake8 extensions as I wanted to compare the two linters.

All documentation I've seen, including that on Microsoft's web site, is that I should be able to select which linter to use by entering the command (ctrl-shft-p) "python: select linter".  However that command does not does not appear in the command list.

Both linter extensions are enabled, and both appear to work, as I get pop up messages with lint corrections.

Has there been a change in the linter selection that does not appear in the documentation?

Comment: @starball In general I don't consider "roll backs" to be a valid solution, although they may work. I've selected an answer below as it explains that the newer versions of the extension no longer have built-in linters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Python: Select Linter` command was removed in the 2023.18.0 release / between that release and the 2023.16.0 release. You can see the command definition and the command palette menu item definition still there in [the 2023.16.0 release's extension manifest](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/blob/v2023.16.0/package.json) (search "`setLinter`"), whereas it's gone in [the 2023.18.0 extension manifest](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/blob/v2023.18.0/package.json).

For more info on why this change (probably) happened, see [Why does the VS Code Python extension (circa v2018.19) no longer provide support for several Python tools like linters and formatters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77283648/11107541). TL;DR the Python extension is deferring linting to separate extensions now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ctrl-shift-p and look for "preferences:Open user settings" and look for setting "**@id:editor.defaultFormatter @lang:python python**" in the "search settings" bar. There, you can pick your preferred linter from the dropdown.