# Visual Studio Code greyed out settings

Tags: visual-studio-code, python-language-server

About 1 hour ago, the YAPF style formatter broke in my vscode. I noticed that the following settings are all now "greyed-out" in settings.json

```
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.lintOnSave": true,
    "python.linting.ignorePatterns": ["**/site-packages/**/*.py", ".vscode/*.py", "research/**/*.py"],
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
    "python.linting.mypyEnabled": false,
    "python.linting.mypyArgs": ["--config-file ~/.mypy.ini"],
    "python.formatting.provider": "yapf",
    "python.formatting.yapfArgs": ["--style={column_limit:120}"],
```

- The Python interpreter is pointing to my virtual environment, in which yapf is installed
- The computer has not re-started between the onset of the faulty behaviour
- The issue appears in a single window (call it X) of vscode, while the issue does not appear in a the second window of vscode (call it Y).

I request a set of settings which accomplish the following goal:

- NEVER attempt to lint or change the file in any way without my direct intervention (formatting on save and the like should never occur)
- When I press the key combination CTRL+SHIFT+I (currently bound to the "Format Document" command), AND my currently selected workspace is a Python file (the language mode in the bottom right hand corner says "Python"), THEN run the following command: `yapf --style={column_limit:120}` and put the output of this command inside the file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the VS Code Python extension (circa v2018.19) no longer provide support for several Python tools like linters and formatters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77283648/why-does-the-vs-code-python-extension-circa-v2018-19-no-longer-provide-support)

Answer (score 0):

If you go in VS Code in the page of the extension, in the tab DETAILS, under section Settings you see what you can specify in the settings.json file.

I couldn't fine every specification that you have, but you can see that for instance

> "python.linting.ignorePatterns" -> "pylint.ignorePatterns"

(I had to change from "python.linting.pylintArgs" to "pylint.args" and the setting was recognized)