# My vscode settings about linting has something wrong,how to solve this problem

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

When opening vscode, it couldn't initialize the linting settings

2023-11-02 21:04:46.011 [error] Following setting is deprecated: "python.linting.flake8Enabled"
2023-11-02 21:04:46.011 [error] All settings starting with "python.linting." are deprecated and can be removed from settings.
2023-11-02 21:04:46.011 [error] Linting features have been moved to separate linter extensions.
2023-11-02 21:04:46.011 [error] See here for more information: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting
2023-11-02 21:04:46.012 [error] Please install "flake8" extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.flake8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJDwL.png)

what's the reason and how to solve this problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the VS Code Python extension (circa v2018.19) no longer provide support for several Python tools like linters and formatters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77283648/why-does-the-vs-code-python-extension-circa-v2018-19-no-longer-provide-support)

Answer (score 10):

In VSCode:

1. Press CTRL+SHIFT+P
2. Type "Open User Settings (JSON)" and press Enter
3. Find and delete the entry starting with "python.linting.flake8Enabled"
4. Other entries starting with "python.linting." can also be deleted as these are also deprecated

   - For example, 'python.linting.pylintArgs' should be moved to 'pylint.args'

If needed, repeat the above steps replacing "User" in step 2 by "Workspace", "Default", "Folder" or "Application".

Installing this extension will likely replace the deprecated functionality: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.flake8

Comment: Would be helpful if you explained how to set these parameters now since they have been deprecated for the settings.json file.

Answer (score 1):

`python.linting` becomes obsolete and as Alexandre said you have to remove the corresponding lines in your `settings.json`.
Now to replace those configuration you should use the specific configs of each of your linters.
For instance with mypy: `"python.linting.mypyCategorySeverity.error": "Warning"` becomes `"mypy-type-checker.severity": {"error": "Warning"}`. To get the new config namespaces you can either use the auto-completion in your `settings.json` or change something in the extension settings (if any) and check the line added at the end of `settings.json`.