# Formatting documents in VS Code 1.84.0

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is this a bug or did they remove the Format document with option from the context menu called by the shortcut  Ctrl + Shift + P?
For example, in version 1.79.2 this option is available

Ctrl + Shift + P then type format
option "Format document with" is expected to appear

Comment: what programming language? what formatters do you have installed and configured for that language? if this is about Python, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/77283648/11107541

Answer (score 0):

you can check whether your python extension version is incompatible with your VS code.
I installed a previous version 2022.16.1, everything works!

Comment: the asker has not yet specified what language they are developing and what formatter they are using for that language. answering questions which are not clear is discouraged. see [answer]. anyhow, if you're going to assume that this is about Python, then you shouldn't have answered, because it'd be a duplicate of the post I linked.