# Autopep8 from venv

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, autopep8

After the day 01/12 my autopep 8 / flake8 / mypy stoped working from VENV, any ideia how to configure this?

```
{
    "[python]": {
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.python",
      "editor.tabSize": 4,
      "editor.insertSpaces": true,
      "editor.formatOnSave": true,
      "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll": true,
        "source.fixAll.unusedImports": true,
        "source.organizeImports": true
      }
    },
    "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
    "python.formatting.autopep8Args": [
      "--indent-size=4",
      "--max-line-length=80"
      // "--ignore=E111"
    ],
    "python.linting.flake8Args": [
      // "--ignore=E111",
    ],
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
    "python.linting.mypyEnabled": true,
    // "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "./venv/scripts/python",
}
```

This is my configs of VSCode, im trying to use the `"python.formatting.provider": "autopep8",` but this dosn't work, and already tried to pass the `autopep8.path` and the `python.pythonPath` to locate them in the venv but still won't work

Comment: possible kind-of-duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/77283648/11107541

Comment: Did you install the corresponding expansion?https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/formatting

Comment: i installed the autopep8 in my "venv", but my vscode don't recognizes it anymore, like its dosn't installed, with this atualization do i need to install it in the vscode global extensions?

edit: the flake8 and mypy installed in the venv stopped working too

Comment: now even installing this is the vscode extensions page the autopep8 dosn't work anymore

Comment: How do they not work? Please describe your steps and your expected and actual results in detail.   Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)