# Can no longer format files in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I used to be able to type CTRL+SHIFT+I or right click and "Format Document".  But now CTRL+SHIFT+I does nothing and when I try to run "Format Document" from the command palette, it says "There is no formatter for coffeescript files installed".  This error message literally does not appear in any google searches.  I tried installing the coffeescript extension, but I still get the error.  I don't know what a coffeescript file is nor should I have to be creating one because this used to work on my vanilla VS Code but now all of a sudden it doesn't.  I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling VS Code but it behaves exactly the same way.  I have no idea how I could lose a functionality I used to have, when I haven't done anything.

Things I have tried:

- Right clicking and looking for "Format Document"
- CTRL+SHIFT+I
- CTRL+SHIFT+P -> "Format Document"
- Install CoffeeScript
- Reinstall VS Code

Comment: what programming languages are you writing in? if you're writing python, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/77283648/11107541

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a default formatter for Coffeescript files in your settings.json like this (you can change whatever formatter you need):

```
{
    "[coffeescript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.json-language-features"
    }
}
```

If your file is not Coffeescript but other file like Javascript or JSON, you can easily change the *Language Mode* for the current file.

[image]

You can assign that every *.coffee* extension files open as javascript Language Mode like this:

```
{
    "files.associations": {
        "*.coffee": "javascript"
    }
}
```