# VSCode - missing options since failed "upgrade" to version 1.86

Tags: visual-studio-code, upgrade

I'm running VSCode on a Mac (High Sierra, hardware means I can't go any newer).

I had the autoupdate turned on, and v1.86 was installed - but it won't run on High Sierra, so I've reverted to v 1.85, and now it works sort-of okay, except the "X" to close split screens has disappeared, and the icon to split screens has also disappeared. Also, when I close tabs the files remain open (so the warnings about code errors remain in the bottom bar). There may be other things that are not working that I haven't come across yet.

Pretty obviously, I've screwed up somewhere, but can anyone tell me how to get this behaviour changed so I can easily un-split the screen, split it again when I want to, and have files close when I close the tab they are in?

Comment: Also noticed that if I right-click in my Python code, the option to "Format" is no longer there.

Comment: about the formatter thing, see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/77283648/11107541

Comment: hi Starball - thanks for this, interesting reading. Just one more thing to put me completely off updating my IDE once I've got it set up the way I like!

Comment: The fastest way I've found to get things "the way they used to be" (including the button for splitting the screen) was to completely junk my settings in both ~/.vscode and ~/Library/Application Support/Code and re-start vscode with a clean environment (I also needed to downgrade VSCode because, having deleted my settings, it auto-updated to the latest version which will not run on my box).

Comment: There has to be a better way, but no-one has suggested one yet!