How to make code formatting work again for Python (Visual Studio Code on Mac)?
On Mac, Option +Shift + F now brings up the "There is no formatter for 'python' files installed." message box:

I tried installing this plugin, without a change seen to this situation:

I already have these two plugins installed for Python:

However as @starball mentioned, it may have reduced support now.
So according to the new world, is there a different way that I can get the on-demand (keyboard shortcut based) automatic code formatting for Python in VSCode to work?
Versions:
VS Code: 1.91.1 (Universal)
Python: 3.12.4

-- what worked finally --
As @klaus-d mentioned, the autopep8 from the Extensions worked!

Here's the list of formatters:  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/formatting#_choose-a-formatter
Thanks everyone!

Try right-click on the file you want to format and look for Format Document. The usual shortcut for that is opt-shift-F

Make sure the "Python", "Pylance" and "autopep8" extensions are installed. All from Microsoft.

I don't have the Format Document option under the right-click context menu.

I have Python, Pylance" and "autopep8 installed. Still no luck. Same popup as mentioned above happens. Restarted both VSCode and Mac, without any change in result.

related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/77283648/11107541... probably not though if you have the autopep8 extension installed

Looks like. But there must be a way to re-activate this code formatting, right? Because a code editor someway does support code formatting. It could be through extensions. Just have to find which way..

Once VSCode Python's format feature came from the python package, VSCode now offers smarter and more customizable extensions.
autopep8 and Black formatter were provided by Microsoft.
Ruff and yapf were provided by community.
Once you install a formatter extension, you can select it as the default formatter for Python files in VS Code by following the steps below:

Open a Python file in VS Code.
Right-click on the editor to display the context menu.
Select Format Document With....
Select Configure Default Formatter... from the drop-down menu.
Select your preferred formatter extension from the list.

You could read document about Formatting in vscode-python for more details.

Black formatter didn't do the Opt+Shift+F formatting. However, autopep8 did the trick!

@MaduKan I tried Black formatter. It should work after you setting the default formatter. You could open your settings(ctrl+,) and search for Editor: Default Formatter then choose the black formatter. You could also check the shortcuts keybinding.

does Black formatter have default key bindings than autopepp8 for formatting?

Their keybinding settings should be the same, you can try to add "[python]": {
"editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter",
"editor.formatOnSave": true
} to your settings.json to check whether the extension work when you save the python file.

Make sure that your "Select Language Mode" is set correctly. If you are working with html select html.

Tried that too. It was already on Python btw.

Try by installing official python extension


I already have the standard Python (official) extension installed

Please don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.
